# How to fill blank rows of excel data with random dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel that looks like

| A |
| --- |
|  |
| 2019/10/1 |
| 2019/8/11 |
| 2019/8/10 |
| 2019/10/10 |
| 2017/10/26 |
|  |
| 2016/10/10 |
| 2020/6/18 |
| 2015/5/8 |
| 2018/10/28 |
| 2019/6/26 |
| 2013/2/2 |
| 2020/9/7 |
| 2019/12/19 |
| 2018/6/6 |
|  |
| 2015/4/9 |
| 2020/4/9 |
| 2020/9/20 |
|  |
| 2016/1/8 |
| 2020/7/20 |
| 2018/9/4 |

There are about 200 blank rows. I want to fill the blank rows with random dates between January and December 2019. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

This macro:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, "A").Value = wf.RandBetween(43466, 43830)
            Cells(i, "A").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

**NOTE(s):**

this:

```
wf.RandBetween(43466, 43830)
```

produces a random date between *1 January 2019* and 31 *December 2019*.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add new column and use below formatting to deal the problem.

```
=IF([A1]="","9/15/19"-RANDBETWEEN(1,60),[A1])
```

Comment: You ***tried*** to do this?  What happened?  If it didn't work for you, you should include it in the question as something you tried.  If it worked, well, "do or do not; there is no *try*". And why ***60**?* … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question and/or your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Yes, it solve my problem

Comment: I was wondering, because it looks like it will give you only dates between 7/17/2019 and 9/14/2019. And those square brackets (``[`` and `]`) look peculiar.